# error ```invalid_arg_type``` when trying to read a specific line form a text file

Tags: javascript

I was trying to read a specific line from a text file using javascript but my program for some reason logs out with an error  `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined`. The line I'm trying to read logs correctly though. I can't figure out what is causing this issue any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function get_line(filename, line_no, callback) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
      flags: 'r',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      fd: null,
      mode: 0666,
      bufferSize: 64 * 1024
    });
 
    var fileData = '';
    stream.on('data', function(data){
      fileData += data;
 
      // The next lines should be improved
      var lines = fileData.split("\n");
 
      if(lines.length >= +line_no){
        stream.destroy();
        callback(null, lines[+line_no]);
      }
    });
 
    stream.on('error', function(){
      callback('Error', null);
    });
 
    stream.on('end', function(){
      callback('File end reached without finding line', null);
    });
 
}
 
get_line('./filepath', 0, function(err, line){
  console.log('The line: ' + line);
})
```

Comment: The code works for me, I can't see any issue, although it may be improved - if you want to read every line of a file in order, you'll open the file many times, which is horrible for performance

Comment: Any reason you can think of why I'm getting an error on my end. @casachii

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: what do you mean by that?@casachii

Comment: I mean I think it's Node.js looking at the error message and the FS module but if so, how do you run it, like a command in the shell

Comment: yeah it's in node js. Powershell@casachii

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231643/discussion-between-casachii-and-anon20010813).

Comment: you code is working check file path './filepath' which you are providing might be wrong

Comment: the path is right as I mentioned above the current code logs the specified line before exiting with an error@RahulKumar